# Is there provision for incremental configuration in shorewall?

Tags: shorewall

I did not find any provision for incremental configuration in [Shorewall](http://shorewall.net). Is there such a mechanism?

What I am looking for is the ability to add configuration files (for rules for instance) in a (again, as an example) `/etc/shorewall/rules.d` folder  - which would be parsed in addition to `/etc/shorewall/rules`.

Such a functionality would help a lot with dynamic configurations where some elements are added/removed as a whole (I have the case of containers which I add and remove in a script and would prefer to handle firewall changes via an addition or removal of files, as opposed to parse one monolithic file)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to an [article](http://developers-club.com/posts/274677/) about shorewall configuration I discovered the `INCLUDE` directive which is well [documented](http://shorewall.net/configuration_file_basics.htm#INCLUDE).

While it is not possible to directly `INCLUDE` wildcard files, the documentation explains how to do it:

> Example (include all of the files ending in ".rules" in a directory:):
>
> (...)
>
> `SHELL cat /etc/shorewall/rules.d/*.rules`